# How to implement multiprocessing in this code?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement multiprocessing for the below code and seems like nothing is working for me.
patterns and output are lists which contain hundreds of thousands of elements.

```
 for pat in patterns:
        for seq in [output[x] for x in range(0, len(output)) if x % 2 != 0]:
            freq = freq + get_count(seq, pat)
        freq_dict[pat] = freq
        freq = 0
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import concurrent  

def add_pattern(pat):
    for seq in [output[x] for x in range(0, len(output)) if x % 2 != 0]:
        freq = freq + get_count(seq, pat)
    freq_dict[pat] = freq
    freq = 0

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(add_pattern, patterns)
```

Comment: If I am using this code, then output list isn't available in the add_pattern function. Is there any way to pass output list to add_pattern function.

Comment: You have two options: 1.- declare output list as a global variable (not recommended) 2.- pass the output list as an additional parameter to add_pattern function. You have to change to executor.map(add_pattern, output_list, patterns)

Comment: Which two options?

Comment: Got that. Will try it :)